# css not selector missing items outside main element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have components in my site that have actions on them but only if not contained in another element.

using css selector not like

```css
:not(.container) > .box
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">kalle</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">palle</div>
  </main>
  <div class="box">olle</div>
</body>
```

will only find 'palle' if context is body
will find both 'palle' and 'olle' if context is html

can someone explain why?

http://jsfiddle.net/4guher4u/2/

Comment: `>` means only direct descendents will be selected. `palle` is not a direct descendant of body and `olle` is no descendant of main at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `body` and `main` elements match the `:not(.container)` selector, as neither of them have a `class` of "container". There is then a direct `.box` child which gets selected.

```html
<!-- Not .container -->
<body> 
  <!-- Not .container -->
  <main>
    <!-- .container, ignored
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">kalle</div>
    </div>
    -->
    <!-- Not .container, is main > .box -->
    <div class="box">palle</div>
  </main>
  <!-- Not .container, is body > .box -->
  <div class="box">olle</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't have much experience using "advanced" css selectors but I think it's odd that 'olle' is not matched when context is body.

.box exists and doesn't have a parent with .container. Logical that is what I'm asking for, but it seems that I'm also implicitly asking for .box with a parent. 

I fixed it using a wider context that made sense in my use case, but in order to understand. Is the '>' telling that .box should have a parent? Could I express it in another way to accomplish my logical search?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("body").find()` you are searching for content **inside** the body. This means that the body is excluded from the search and won't match the `:not(.container)` selector and then `<div class="box">olle</div>` won't match the `not(.container) > .box` selector, because it's not inside any element.

When you search inside the `html` element, with `$("html").find()`, the `:not(.container)` selector matches against `body`, because it is a child of `html`, and so `<div class="box">olle</div>` matches the `:not(.container) > .box` selector because it is inside the body.